# Django view with related value in a list of list

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I have a Creator and Listing model, in one of html template, I need to display the Listing attributes and the Creator attribute associated with it, I tried to get all unique creators and put that in set but my Listing is a list of lists, I need to get all attributes from both models which matches  creator attribute and an element list of listing. I guess Django has a better approach for this, may be I am doing all wrong, here is what I tried so far.

Model

```
class Creator:
      first_name =models.CharField(max_length=200)
      last_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
       photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%d/')

class Listing:
    creator = models.ForeignKey(Creator, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    ....More fields

View 



def index(request):
    creators = set()
    listings_by_creator = set()
    for e in Listing.objects.filter(is_published=True).select_related('creator'):
        creators.add(e.creator)
        if any(x != e.creator for x in listings_by_creator ):
            listings_by_creator.add(e)

context = {'zipped_app_list': zip(listings_by_creator, creators)}


template

  {% if zipped_app_list %}
      {% for list_of_listing,creator  in zipped_app_list %}
         .............

      Now I need to display creator value and item with creator value in list_of_listing
```